# Identify & hover on invisble webelement-Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to automate a scenario where in i have to hover on a `webelement` & click on it !! too simple !!

Now the complicated part is the element is a hidden element & becomes visible only on mouse hover.

Things i have tried the below methods too which didn't work:

1. Actions class- This seems to be useless in my scenario because my element isn't even visible for this method to work
2. Robot class- This seems to work partially with movement of mouse but problem with it is that it cannot convert the mouse movement into gestures i.e it simply moves the mouse pointer over the element & the element does not get active & allow to be clicked like a manual mouse pointer movement.

Below is the element detail & code i tried which didn't work:

```
Webelement test=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myid']/div[2]/div/span/form/button"));
Point coordinates = test.getLocation();
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX(),coordinates.getY()+120);
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you seeing your mouse pointer location is on that disabled button ?- using robot class solution

Comment: yes the mouse pointer correctly moves on that disabled element but its not able to highlight & make it visible unlike manual way.

Comment: can you add some `html` code ?

Comment: <button class="follow" value="follow" type="submit" title="Add to Favourites" name="commit">Follow</button>

Comment: have u tried using `JavascriptExecuter` like `WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Add to Favourites'][name='commit']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

Comment: JS executer seems to work & is like the final option here, but i was preferring morever for a human action mimiked alternative

Comment: can you share your site `url` if possible ?

Comment: sorry buddy due to privacy clauses of the organization i cannot disclose the url but its a Nodejs based webapp.